# lightning:picklistPath how to cancel clicking

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using the almost new [lightning:picklistPath](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_picklistPath.htm):

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId">
    <lightning:picklistPath aura:id="picklistPath"
                    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    variant="linear"
                    picklistFieldApiName="Status__c" />
</aura:component>
```

On loading it looks like that:

[image]

When I click on one of the steps, it gets selected and I do not need that, for example - I have clicked on the second step `Approval` and now it looks like that:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent clicking, or prevent the clicking from changing the display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible.

We had the same issue and rebuild this path component ourselves by using the guidance of the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/).

In our version, we override certain functions and styles. For example, hovering over a value does not turn the cursor into a 'ClickMe' but still changes the hue slightly.

Comment: So your actual answer is 'not possible'?

Comment: yes. I have updated the answer as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, can your share your solution?

Comment: Cannot for legal reasons. Truly sorry.

Comment: I am not marking this answer as completed yet because I hope a good answer with a `THIS IS POSSIBLE` will come

Comment: as of today this is not possible so I vote on this answer

Answer (score 6):

It is possible using standard css. You can put the lightning path in a div and use the *pointer-events: none* property to make the lightning path unclickable.

```
<div style="pointer-events:none;">
     <lightning:picklistPath recordId="{!v.recordId}" picklistFieldApiName="..." onselect="..." />
</div>
```